# Las Vegas algorithm versus Monte-Carlo algorithm in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, integration, algorithms

I used the las Vegas algorithm to calculate the multidimensional integrals of a cross-section in tree-level. I don't quite understand what the Monte Carlo algorithm is for: Could I also calculate with it the multidimensional integrals?
I read that the Las Vegas algorithm gives always the right solution and Monte-Carlo only with a certain probability the right solution: So why should we use Monte Carlo simulations? Or do we need Monte Carlo for calculations in loop-level? If yes, why can't we use the las Vegas algorithm in loop-level?

Comment: There is not "the standard Las Vegas algorithm for integration". What do you do exactly? Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm#Relation_to_Monte_Carlo_algorithms points out the in my opinion key difference between Las Vegas type and Monte Carlo type algorithms: the first one does not necessarily return a correct result in a finite time whereas the latter one does.
In turn, the first one returns a correct result whereas the latter one does return a correct result whereas the latter one returns a probably correct result including an uncertainty depending on the implementation.